# Laravel 4, Auth model not persistent after successful Auth::attempt()

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I was able to use Auth::attempt to log in successfully. However, when I use Auth::check() or Auth::user()->id I get a non-object error.

My sessions are working correctly, I have tested this with Session::put/get.

What else should I check to try and correct his issue?

Comment: How do you know you have logged in successfully?

Comment: I used dd(Auth::check()) and it shows true.

Comment: So what happens when you do dd(Auth::user())?